# List of lists in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, addition

I am trying to create lists, that are then inserted into another list.
For some reason the latter list gets overwritten each time I try to add new list item to it.
For the code below, first I want to add items to `Temp` list and after certain conditions have been met, add the `Temp` list as an item to the `Comp` list. After that, the cycle repeats, new and different `Temp` list should be created and the added to the `Comp` list as next item. So each item in `Comp` list should be different.
But in the end I get a `Comp` list that is filled with `Temp` lists that are all identical to the last `Temp` list added.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Function UniqueValueList2(ByVal InputObject As List(Of Object)) As List(Of List(Of Object))
    Dim vc As Integer = InputObject.Count
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim Temp As New List(Of Object)
    Dim Comp As New List(Of List(Of Object))

    Dim CurrentObj As String
    Dim PrevObj As String

    Temp.Add(InputObject(0))

    Do While i < vc
        CurrentObj = InputObject(i).fieldName
        PrevObj = InputObject(i-1).fieldName

        If CurrentObj = PrevObj Then
            Temp.Add(InputObject(i))
        Else
            Comp.Add(Temp)
            Temp.Clear()
            Temp.Add(InputObject(i))
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Comp.Add(Temp)
    UniqueValueList2 = Comp
End Function
```

Comment: Why use List(Of Object)?  It seems to me that it completely negates the benefits of generic types.  You may as well just use an ArrayList.

Comment: Because I'd like to have a list of class objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temp is holding the same reference. so making changes on it will change it.And you  add and modify the same List

```
 Comp.Add(Temp) 'the same Temp List
 Temp.Clear() 'You will clear the same List
 Temp.Add(InputObject(i))
```

So How you should do :

```
Comp.Add(Temp) 'we add old List
Temp=New List(Of Object) 'Temp now holds reference to new List
Temp.Add(InputObject(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Comp.Add(Temp.ToList())
Temp.Clear()
Temp.Add(InputObject(i))
```